How to use google sheets so each user can edit only their one row, and see all rows
I am trying to build an online repository for simple information, where a user can enter/edit their own data, and view the rest of the data.  Essentially, each user would have edit access to their own single-row in a table.  I want to minimize set up/maintenance of "accounts"; I want this to be a no-cost solution.
I imagine a set of solutions --- google sheets, google sheets with forms, an online survey setup.   Beyond by-user edit permissions, ease of maintenance is my primary goal.
I would have full authority over the whole data set.
If plausible, I imagine a publicly available spreadsheet, available to anyone with a google account, where google ID is a column, and with other, simple columns (e.g., name and an integer).
Each person logging in and accessing the spreadsheet would:

have edit access to their own row, except the account column.
find their google account in the first column (which automatically has their own google account in the first column), and
have view access to the entire spreadsheet, except the first column (google account column).

Anyone using the sheet:

for the first time would do so by logging in to google, and a row would be created with their google account in the first column.
would be granted the appropriate row edit permission, automatically.
on returning later, they would have permission on an already existing row (their own); therefore the google account column is normalized.

A potentially useful gloss is a way to exclude a subset of google accounts, based on abuse -- I imagine a simple interface where I mark column with an "X" which (if present) denies views to the whole spreadsheet to that row's user.
I am program and spreadsheet hardy, from years of various use, including VBA in excel, but no experience in the google docs / sheets world (other than editing my own spreadsheet, there).
I considered surveys, but need edit permissions.  If I had a survey type setup, I imagine that the data, or summaries (counts, avg of a number column) would not be accessible as people filled out or later edited their own answers.   Because of this, a spreadsheet seems to fit the bill, better.
Suggestions?   Don't need a ginned up spreadsheet, unless its simple to do, but a description of the specific steps involved would help.  Alternative solutions, appreciated.
Again, my goals are initial simplicity to set up, and then simplicity of use/maintenance.  I am aiming at ... free, otherwise.
Thanks...

Creating Automatic Protected Cells
Recommendation:
Based on the description on your post, this perfectly explains the use of Protected Ranges on Google Apps Script. Here is the link for the reference. Apps Script reference for this is on this link.
During the set up process what you want to Do is a Simple Trigger Called OnOpen(). During this process you can set up a protective range and get the User's Email using the getActiveUserMethod(). For selective editing properties of a Google Sheet. This will automate the process of the set up which means close to nothing in terms of maintenance aside from periodic update in case an Apps Script method is updated. Everyone will still have access to the Spreadsheet the only thing limited was what ranges are they allowed to edit.
Note:
Anyone who can edit, a Google Sheet should be an Editor of the Spreadsheet. There is no work around it aside from Running things using a Web App it will run things using publishers access levels. Though it could be a viable solution with your it will only further complexity of the project that generates the same result with what is stated above. Feel free to read more about Web Apps here. Depending on how the data is presented and what type of data is being accepted, you can expand the protection as a Sheet and just create a Primary cell to Collect the data from other sheets to be more presentable and easier editing procedures.

Please feel free to reach out if you have any questions about this.

